# How to decrypt a combination of transposition and substitution cipher text

Tags: substitution-cipher, decryption

I'm having problems decrypting a cipher text that has an transposition cipher applied to it but also a substitution cipher. I don't know in which order they were applied. Does anyone know what steps I should follow to decrypt it?

Comment: I guess an anagram in this case is a transposition cipher? Trying to find anagrams would be trying to solve the transposition cipher I guess.

Comment: Could you please edit and describe exactly what an anagram is in this case.

Comment: Looking at your questions, it seems you are having trouble with assignments for a crypto course. It is much better to look at assistance within the course itself, as it is hard for us to tell what you have tried and where you are stuck. Explaining the full attacks is overly broad, and we're certainly not prepared to go through all the steps for each student that is stuck.